# Connect to EasyVPN from Hamachi VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

Normally a problem like this would be solved using port forwarding, however our ISP doesn't use one  IP address per customer, so we appear to be coming from a broadcast address (or similar)

We host a game using hamachi VPN, but hamachi only supports 15 players per server, so we have decided to use EasyVPN.

We wanted to create or to host a gaming network that uses a VPN - is it possible to use Hamachi VPN to connect to EasyVPN?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, and what I know about Hamachi, I don't think that's possible. Hamachi uses its own servers for network info, so Hamachi has no way to find the EasyVPN network. They may also use different communication protocols.

You could probably host both a Hamachi network and an EasyVPN network. That would allow 15 people with Hamachi to connect to the game, while more could connect using EasyVPN.